# C Linked List Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linked-list

It says I have a segmentation fault in the insert function, though I can't seem to find it. I did allocate the pointer with the size but it still gives a segmentation fault.

Here is my code:

this is my struct:

```
typedef struct Lists{
        int x;
        struct Lists *next;
}List;
```

this is the main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        if(argc<2){ 
                printf("Error");
                return 0;
        }       
        List *root;
        int count = 0;
        root =malloc(sizeof(List)*atoi(argv[2])); 
        srand(atoi(argv[1]));
        while(count<atoi(argv[2])){
                int randomNumber = rand() % atoi(argv[3]);
                printf("Random Number is: %d",randomNumber);
                insertNodeSorted(root,randomNumber);
                count++;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

this is the function where a Segmentation Fault occurs:

```
 void insertNodeSorted(List *root,int randomNumber){
            List *temp,*node;
            node =malloc(sizeof(List));
            node->x = randomNumber;
            root=malloc(sizeof(List));
            temp = root;
            if(root==NULL){
                    root->x = randomNumber;
                    return;
            }
            while(temp != NULL){
                    if(randomNumber < temp->x){
                            node->next = root;
                            root = node;
                            break;
                    }
                    else if(randomNumber >= temp->x && randomNumber < temp->next->x){
                            node->next = temp->next;
                            temp->next = node;
                            break;
                    }
                    if(temp->next == NULL){
                            temp->next = node;
                            break;
                    }
                    temp = temp->next;
            }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem related to the program, but the check `argc<2` isn't enough to check the availability of `argv[2]` and `argv[3]`.

Comment: The function `insertNodeSorted` smells because the value of passed parameter `root` isn't used and memory leak happens.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* will be invoked when `temp->next`, which is indeterminate value from space allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized, is used at the line `else if(randomNumber >= temp->x && randomNumber < temp->next->x)`.

Comment: `if(root==NULL){ root->x = ...` Nonsense. Do not dereference `NULL`.

Comment: Also note that change of `root` in the function `insertNodeSorted()` will NOT affect `root` in the `main()` function.

Comment: Install GDB and Valgrind and step through your code with GDB. Finding Seg Faults by hand is a brutally inefficient use of time. Use Valgrind to find memory leaks and allocation errors.